# report in excel from Jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

While generating report in excel, following error message are shown. Please help!!!

Code:-

```
public String mainReportXLS(){

    Map<String, Object> jrxmlParams = null;

    try{

        String jrxmlFileName = "C:/Jasper/Dashboard2.jrxml";

        JasperReport objJReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlFileName);
        connection = getConnection();

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(objJReport, jrxmlParams, connection);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputByteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //OutputStream outputfile= new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/output/JasperReport.xls"));

         JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
         exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
         exporterXLS.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "C:/Jasper/Dashboard2.xls" );
         exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputByteArray);
         exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
         exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
         exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
         exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
         exporterXLS.exportReport();

         //outputfile.write(outputByteArray.toByteArray()); 


    }catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.print("Exceptiion" + e);
      }

    return null;
}
```

Error Message viewed:--

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
javax.faces.FacesException: Error calling action method of component with id headerForm:Report123456
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:72)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastForPhase(UIViewRoot.java:97)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:171)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Exception while invoking expression #{ReportsBB.extractJasper}
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:61)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastForPhase(UIViewRoot.java:97)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:171)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getCreationHelper()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper;
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.openWorkbook(JRXlsExporter.java:282)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReportToStream(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:879)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReport(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:629)
    at com.ultimatix.dealpricing.dao.ReportsDAO.mainReportXLS(ReportsDAO.java:137)
    at com.ultimatix.dealpricing.backingbeans.ReportsBackingBean.extractJasper(ReportsBackingBean.java:293)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Can any one pls help..!!!

Answer (score 5):

Please try the following code , It worked for me

```
   File xlsx = new File("C:/Users/Sadagopan/Documents/sample.xlsX");
   JRXlsxExporter Xlsxexporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
   Xlsxexporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,
                             jasperPrint);
   Xlsxexporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE,
                             xlsx);
   Xlsxexporter.exportReport();
```

check this as well .. "Tools" > "Options" > "Export Options" tab > "PDF" various options for security

Comment: thanks again.. There is one more doubt, I need to disable the pdf Toolbar once the report is generated in PDF. Have tried some parameters from JRPDFExporter... but was unable to implement. My project requirement includes disabling of save and print option from PDF. Can you kindly suggest. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please vote up the above answer .. Did you try this option:`jasperreports.export.pdf.encrypted` for pdf security ?

Comment: check this as well ..  "Tools" > "Options" > "Export Options" tab > "PDF" various options for security.

Comment: yes have tried and have been successful in getting the Save disable. But it is browser dependent. Working fine in explorer and sometime not working in Mozilla